# how can I access values stored within a method from other places of a class

Tags: c#, .net, variables, methods

In my current application while I have been able to implement the required logic that I need I am really stuck when trying to take off the content from the main method and using it from a different method .

My code is as below,

```
class Program
    {
        const string path = @"filePath";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            setUpValues();
        }
        private static void setUpValues()
        {
                var Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<deploy>(File.ReadAllText(path));
                List<Variable> variables = Content.Variables.ToList();
                Scopes Scope = Content.ScopeValues;

                string Version = null;

                List<string> ListOfSelectedItems= new List<string>();
                List<string> TempListOfSelectedItems = new List<string>();
                List<string> Channels = new List<string>();

            foreach (var item in variables)
            {
                if (item.Name.Equals("version"))
                {
                    Version = item.Value;
                }
                if (item.Name.Equals("Selected"))
                {
                    TempListOfSelectedItems.Add(item.Value);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Version  " + Version);
            Console.WriteLine();

            string SelectedItems= TempListOfSelectedItems[0];
            ListOfSelectedItems = SelectedItems.Split(',').ToList();

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Selected Modules");
            Console.WriteLine();

            foreach (var item in ListOfSelectedItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

            foreach (var item in Scope.Channels)
            {
                Channels.Add(item.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to be able to access the variable string Version ,  the List of ListOfSelectedItems and the List of channels from outside this method .. I want to use these in another as well . So how can I make these globally accessible ?
Would really appreciate your help on this as I have been stuck here

Comment: make them (static) _members_ of your class (like `path`, but not as `const`).

Comment: well that path is a constant and I want to keep it that way ... Any idea how I can access  tring Version , the List of ListOfSelectedItems and the List of channels ? @RenéVogt

Comment: Like Path, does not mean change path. Path is accessible everywhere, you want something accesible everywhere, so take path as an example for what you want to do. (but replace const by static, as Rene said)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use variables outside a method, you should declare them as fields of a class. Like this:

```
class Program
{
    const string path = @"filePath";
    static deploy Content;
    static string Version;
    static List<string> ListOfSelectedItems;
    static List<string> TempListOfSelectedItems;
    static List<string> Channels;
    // and others

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        setUpValues();
    }

    private static void setUpValues()
    {
        Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<deploy>(File.ReadAllText(path));
        List<Variable> variables = Content.Variables.ToList();
        Scopes Scope = Content.ScopeValues;

        Version = null;

        ListOfSelectedItems = new List<string>();
        TempListOfSelectedItems = new List<string>();
        Channels = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in variables)
        {
            if (item.Name.Equals("version"))
            {
                Version = item.Value;
            }

            if (item.Name.Equals("Selected"))
            {
                TempListOfSelectedItems.Add(item.Value);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Version  " + Version);
        Console.WriteLine();

        string SelectedItems = TempListOfSelectedItems[0];
        ListOfSelectedItems = SelectedItems.Split(',').ToList();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Selected Modules");
        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (var item in ListOfSelectedItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        foreach (var item in Scope.Channels)
        {
            Channels.Add(item.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

You have to declare those fields as `static` because they are used in a static method. After the `setUpValues` finishes running, you can use those fields inside the `Main` method as well.

Also, this is not related to the question, but the general code convention in C# is to start methods' names with an uppercase letter (so `SetUpValues` instead of `setUpValues`) and to start the local variables' names with a lowercase letter (`selectedItems` instead of `SelectedItems`). Obviously, it's ultimately up to you how to name things and which code convention to use.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer . Just have a small problem tho. Right after the method finishes executing the values are null again . am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: I think it may be because you have static fields and then in the method you declare the local variables _with the same name_. I can't be sure, though, because I can't see the code. To use a field instead of a local variable you should for example use this: `ListOfSelectedItems = ...` instead of this: `List<string> ListOfSelectedItems = ...`. When you write `type name`, you create a new variable, which can have the same name as the field, but it's a completely separate thing.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with properties that you want to access from other places. Instantiate this class in setUpValues and return this.

```
public class TestClass
{
    public TestClass()
    {
        this.ListOfSelectedItems = new List<string>();
    }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public List<string> ListOfSelectedItems { get; set; }
}
```

And then modify your Main method as:

```
    var myObj = setUpValues();
```

And then Modify setUpValues to return this:

```
    private static TestClass setUpValues()
    {
        var Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<deploy>(File.ReadAllText(path));
        List<Variable> variables = Content.Variables.ToList();
        Scopes Scope = Content.ScopeValues;

        string Version = null;

        List<string> ListOfSelectedItems = new List<string>();
        List<string> TempListOfSelectedItems = new List<string>();
        List<string> Channels = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in variables)
        {
            if (item.Name.Equals("version"))
            {
                Version = item.Value;
            }
            if (item.Name.Equals("Selected"))
            {
                TempListOfSelectedItems.Add(item.Value);
            }
        }
        var retObj = new TestClass();
        Console.WriteLine("Version  " + Version);
        Console.WriteLine();
        retObj.Version = Version;
        string SelectedItems = TempListOfSelectedItems[0];
        ListOfSelectedItems = SelectedItems.Split(',').ToList();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Selected Modules");
        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (var item in ListOfSelectedItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
            retObj.ListOfSelectedItems.Add(item);
        }

        foreach (var item in Scope.Channels)
        {
            Channels.Add(item.Name);
        }

        return retObj;
    }
```